# How to find a transformation matrix having several original points and their respective transformed results?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

I have three original points $pt_1, pt_2, pt_3$ which if transformed by an unknown matrix $M$ turn into points $gd_1, gd_2, gd_3$ respectively. How can I find the matrix $M$ (all points are in 3-dimensional space)?

I understand that for original points holds $M\cdot pt_i = gd_i$, so combining all $pt_i$ into matrix $PT$ and all $gd_i$ into $GD$ I'd get a matrix equation $M\cdot PT=GD$ with unknown $M$.

However, many math packages solve matrix equations in form of $A\cdot x=B$, where $x$ is unknown.

Is my idea of combining points into matrices correct and if so how can I solve my matrix equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Form matrices whose rows are $pt_k$ and $gd_k$. Then
$$
\begin{bmatrix}pt_1\\pt_2\\pt_3\end{bmatrix}M=\begin{bmatrix}gd_1\\gd_2\\gd_3\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then we have
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}pt_1\\pt_2\\pt_3\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}gd_1\\gd_2\\gd_3\end{bmatrix}
$$
So your idea is correct.

Comment: Doh, how couldn't I figure it out!

Comment: Wait, why rows? In your mind, if $A$ is a matrix, $X$ and $B$ are vectors, then which notation is correct: $A\cdot X=B$ or $X\cdot A=B$?

Comment: Small addition: you didn't say whether the space is 3-dimensionsal. If you have less points than dimensions, you can still find a matrix that does what you want, but it is not unique. You should use [pseudo Inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse).

Comment: @mbaitoff: Oops... I should have put the matrix on the right or used columns. I have moved the matrix to the right, so as to be proper with row vectors.

Comment: @yohBS: and if we have more points than dimensions, we can use a [least squares regression](http://www.whim.org/nebula/math/affineregress.html).

Comment: @robjohn it's practically the same, I think.

Comment: Least squares regression will not handle an underdetermined system. A pseudo-inverse on a fully determined system is just the inverse; it still requires a least squares regression on an overdetermined system. Although both problems require a minimization of squares, they are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe the accepted answer works for translations. If we have a three-dimensional point and a 3x3 transformation matrix, the zero point will always map to the zero point.

A general affine transformation requires a four-dimensional matrix.
It may be possible to use a four-dimensional point with the fourth component of the point equal to 1.